# I have 2 outlets from front and back of the house that have no current

Tags: electrical

I have 2 outlets from front and back of the house that have no power, and I check my breakers they all on and everything else in the house is working except there is no current to these outlets so i don't know how these outlets are tied to.
How can I repair them?

Comment: Did they used to work and have suddenly stopped working or have they _never_ worked? Do you have an [outlet tester](https://www.amazon.com/outlet-tester/s?k=outlet+tester)? The pro's call it a [Magic 8-Ball](https://magic-8ball.com/) because they're not _super_ accurate, but they're enough for a rookie to get an idea what's going on - you may simply have had a wire come loose. Without knowing what breaker this is on, it's a good first step to testing without having to turn the power off to the whole house to stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

Since outside receptacles have required GFCI protection for a long time there is probably a GFCI receptacle inside the home that is protecting these.

With the receptacles required at front and back they are quite often fed from a receptacle close to the door that is a GFCI. Reset this and they will probably be fine. Sometimes the receptacle inside is on the other side of the wall.

Prior to WR rated GFCI receptacles it was common to put them inside. After weather ratings became a thing it made more sense to put them outside as the moisture no longer was a problem (the electronics are potted) this is an encapsulated coating that seals the electronics from moisture.

You might also check for switches as many outside receptacles are put on switches so they can control holiday lighting.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the connections to these have been removed over the years leaving these outlets redundant. You will need to see if you can find out from the outlet where the wires go so you can perhaps find out where/when/why the connection was removed.